# Implement search Using Jquery in repeated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I am new to jquery. Currently I am developing a chat application . Functionality and everything works fine, but my current need is that, I have to put a search box in user list page, so client can search particular user and chat with him/her
please see the screenshot of my chat list page

[image]

For listing I have used div not ul & li. So my need is how can i search through the div? , my user listing code is below

```
<div class="chatpage-usersListMainDiv" style="height: 502px;">
<div><input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="search_criteria" onkeyup="myFunction()"></div>
<div class="col-md-7 chat_chatboxDisplayDetails"><div class="chat_userdisplayname">Teenu Thomas</div></div>
<div class="col-md-7 chat_chatboxDisplayDetails"><div class="chat_userdisplayname">Justin Luka</div></div>
<div class="col-md-7 chat_chatboxDisplayDetails"><div class="chat_userdisplayname">David John</div></div>
<div class="col-md-7 chat_chatboxDisplayDetails"><div class="chat_userdisplayname">Agnes Era</div></div>
</div>
```

The html data displayed as above.
My java script function is below

```
function myFunction(){
    var input, filter, ser_div, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('search_criteria');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
     ser_div= document.getElementsByTagName("search_tag");

}
```

From here I cant go forward , how can dispaly ony the div with matched name? please help

Comment: Sulu, do you still face the problem or have any of the solutions helped you?

Comment: now I am implementing it, as of now it is working. If I struck, will contact u. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the elements containing the name.

```
var people = document.getElementsByClassName("chat_userdisplayname");
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  var name = people[i].innerHTML;
  if (name.startsWith(input.value)) {
    people[i].style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    people[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

This will loop through all elements with the class `chat_userdisplayname` and then check if the name starts with our input value.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ser_div, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById('search_criteria');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ser_div = document.getElementsByTagName("search_tag");

  var people = document.getElementsByClassName("chat_userdisplayname");
  for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    var name = people[i].innerHTML;
    if (name.startsWith(input.value)) {
      people[i].parentElement.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      people[i].parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chatpage-usersListMainDiv" style="height: 502px;">
  <div><input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="search_criteria" onkeyup="myFunction()"></div>
  <div class="col-md-7 chat_chatboxDisplayDetails">
    <div class="chat_userdisplayname">Teenu Thomas</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 chat_chatboxDisplayDetails">
    <div class="chat_userdisplayname">Justin Luka</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 chat_chatboxDisplayDetails">
    <div class="chat_userdisplayname">David John</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 chat_chatboxDisplayDetails">
    <div class="chat_userdisplayname">Agnes Era</div>
  </div>
</div>
```